# How do I override a Magento Core module?

Tags: interface, magento, module, overriding, admin

I want to modify the code for the Order/Sales table in the admin interface and the PDF generation code without alterting the files in the `core` directory. How do I do this? I understand that I have to create a new module that uses the same paths as the files I want to overwrite, but I'm not sure what else I have to do...are there some special steps to go through for the `config.xml` of the module??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do it in a separate module, you should put your new model (block, helper or whatever you need to override - I'll be using the model example, its the same for the others - only the controllers are quite different) in the 'Model' directory (for instance: code/local/MyNamespace/MyModule/Model/Sales/Order.php). In your modules config.xml you should add:

```
<global>
(...)
  <models>
    (...)
    <sales>
      <rewrite>
        <order>MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Sales_Order</order>
      </rewrite>
    </sales>
  </models>
(...)
</global>
```

Of course your own Sales_Order model should inherit from the core one. This is the cleanest way to override Magento core functionality (maybe besides events, but they can't do everything).

Answer (score 0):

Create matching directories and files that you want modified in the local folder for the module.  That should be all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

As mcmil correctly pointed out, create a module in your own namespace and extend from the core class. By doing this you are writing less code and creating less bloat. It also improves your upgrade path in the future.

If you simply copy the whole file from app/code/core to app/code/local and then the core file/class gets changed in the next Magento update you might miss out on those changes. If you are extending from the core class with your module then your new class will inherit those changes when you update Magento.